# Ubuntu 14.04 Snap to 1/4 of the screen instead of 1/2

Tags: unity, 14.04

I have a 4k monitor on my system, I would like to change how ubuntu snaps windows, I would like it to only snap to like the upper right, upper left ext.... instead of just the left or just the right

I know in older versions of ubnutu you could change these settings in compiz but I do not see compiz on my system.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-config-settings-manager
```

Run `ccsm` to open it.

You might be looking for the `Grid` or the `Snapping Windows` section.

Comment: Is there any reason why this would not install on 16.04? E: Unable to locate package compiz-config-settings-manager

Comment: Not so much explained :-V you have to enter Grid options, then enter Corner/Edges tab. There are already defined values, just needs to set the proper action for both top/bottom left and right actions. What can't be done is the key assignement cuz don't lets you to press Super+Ctrl+Up+Right in example. I do remember that works in other distros but not there and i am not sure if it's doable. Actually it's defined into numeric pad, which i have not :C so it's a bit useless if i can't set Grid position by keyboard but still better than just have half a screen. Thanks.